# Compare two column in differents worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that compare two columns in a different worksheet and highlight the matched cells with the green color

but the problem that both column got over than 9000 line so if I use this

```
for i =1 to lastrow
```

it will take over than 5 min matching values and giving results

```
 Dim i As Variant, j As Integer, k As Integer


'lastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

'lastrow1 = Sheets(2).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastRow1 = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 8 To 9252
If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then

   For j = 1 To 9252
        If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheets(2).Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

        End If
        Next j
 Else
    i = i + 1
    End If
    Next i
```

What I want is to find a solution to compare the two columns using Lastrow and find an efficient solution with no delays

Anyone got a clue about this  ?

Best Regards 
Polos

Comment: How often do you get more than a single match on the alternate worksheet  for a value?

Comment: Did you try conditional formatting rather than VBA?

Comment: @Jeeped just 4 or 5 times

Comment: @johnColeman I need to use VBA code in this case to adapt alot of things later and modification

Comment: Why are you advancing your counter (`i = i + 1`) if the cell in Sheet1 is blank? The For ... Next takes care of that.

Comment: good remarque :)  I'm gonna delete that , I think I was wasting time using i=i+1

Comment: Actually, `i = i + 1` was skipping over rows.

Comment: which can  lead to incorrect values  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to find the value from Sheet1 on Sheet2; it doesn't matter if there are more than one matching value on Sheet2. Application.Match will locate identical values much faster than looping through all rows.

```
dim i as long, f as variant

with workSheets(1)
    for i=8 to .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        f = application.match(.cells(i, "A").value2, workSheets(2).columns("A"), 0)
        if not iserror(f) then
            .cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        end if
    next i
end with
```

With your original double-loop, even if the value from Sheet1 was found in the 10th row in Sheet2, you still kept comparing through the loop until row 9252. The cell in Sheet1 can only be colored once.

Comment: just to clarify with  , As I see here  "i" starts from 8 and J doesn't exist  ??? because in the second sheets values located  and started from a different line

Comment: Sheet1 starts at row 8; the entire column A on Sheet2 is examined. Your own code started Sheet2's column A loop at the first row.

Comment: if I want to modify the row of the sheet 2 how can i manage that ?? ? thank you in advance

Comment: Change `workSheets(2).columns("A")` to `workSheets(2).range("a1:a9252")` and adjust the row numbers. However, unless you are worried about matching something above or below the specified range, any advantage is infinitesimal.

Comment: @Jeeped I like your minimalist code! Only a small correction, `.cells(i, "A").Interior.ColorIndex = 4` should be `.cells(i, "D").Interior.ColorIndex = 4`, although I`m sure the OP will notice soon enough.

Comment: @DarXyde - Yes, I noticed the discrepancy between `lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and `If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = ...` in the original code. That was one of the factors in deciding on using `.cells(i, "A")` style syntax instead of `.cells(i, 1)` style. Thankfully, it seems the OP has managed to split the difference and arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a dictionary as a set data structure to hold the values in sheet 2 and then use this dictionary in sheet 1. This will have the effect of changing your quadratic algorithm into a linear algorithm:

```
Sub ColorMatches()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim R As Range, cl As Range
    Dim D As Object
    Dim vals As Variant

    'load dictionary from sheet 2
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    lastRow = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    vals = Sheets(2).Range("A8:A" & lastRow).Value
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If Not D.exists(vals(i, 1)) Then D.Add vals(i, 1), 0
    Next i

    'use dictionary in sheet 1
    lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set R = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    For Each cl In R.Cells
        If D.exists(cl.Value) Then cl.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Next cl

End Sub
```

As a small but potentially important point: note that I used `Long` for `i` rather than `Integer` for row indices (as you did in your code). Modern versions of Excel have more rows than can be represented by an `Integer` variable, and 16 -bit ints are likely to be stored using 32 bits, so using `Integer` just risks overflow for no corresponding gain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick. I'm not an expert, but learned the hard way a simple lesson: **The less you interact with the sheets, the faster it works!**

```
Option Explicit                                                             'Is worth using this option, so you remember declaring your variables

Sub SO()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim arrRange1 As Variant, arrRange2 As Variant, arrColor As Variant         'Declare arrays
ReDim arrColor(0)                                                           'Initial redim

Dim lastRow As Long                                                         'Only need to use one variable for this, and reassign as needed through the code
Dim sh1 As Worksheet: Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RandomSheetName 1")    'Declare sheet 1
Dim sh2 As Worksheet: Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RandomSheetName 2")    'Declare sheet 2

    With sh1
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                    'Get last row from sheet 1 in column "A"
        arrRange1 = .Range(.Cells(8, 4), .Cells(lastRow, 4))                'Get all values from column "D", starting at row 8
    End With
    With sh2
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                    'Get last row from sheet 2 in column "A"
        arrRange2 = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))                'Get all values from column "A", starting at row 1
    End With

    For i = LBound(arrRange1) To UBound(arrRange1)                          'Loop through first sheet values
        If arrRange1(i, 1) <> "" Then                                       'If not empty, then...
            For j = LBound(arrRange2) To UBound(arrRange2)                  'Loop through second sheet values
                If arrRange1(i, 1) = arrRange2(j, 1) Then                   'If match, then...
                    ReDim Preserve arrColor(k)                              'Redim (preserve) the colours array
                    arrColor(k) = i + 7                                     'Add the value of i in the colours array (note +7, since yours sheet1 values start at row 8, feel free to amend)
                    k = k + 1                                               'Increase the counter for the colours array
                    Exit For                                                'As per idea from the accepted response, no point to check the whole sheet2 range if duplicate found already
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                      'It always helps to turn off the screenupdating when working with the sheets
    For i = LBound(arrColor) To UBound(arrColor)                            'Loop through the colours array
        If arrColor(0) = "" Then Exit For                                   'If the first element is empty, means no matches... exit here.
        sh1.Cells(arrColor(i), 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 4                   'Colour the cell as needed using the value we previously stored
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                                       'And lets not forget to turn it on again

End Sub
```

PS: please note that `Rows.Count` it will give you the count from the `ActiveSheet`, not from `Sheet1` or `Sheet2`. You need to make full reference, i.e.: `Sheets(1).Rows.Count`

So this:

```
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

it should be

```
lastRow = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

or

```
With Sheets(1)
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Hope this helps!